# Does WSO2 ESB support web sockets?

Tags: websocket, real-time, wso2, real-time-updates, wso2-esb

My project needs to provide read and write access to data using web services (SOAP/JSON etc), but we also need the ability to serve real-time notifications of data changes to external users through websockets. Does WSO2's ESB support this capability?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, currently no support for websockets..but, you could write data to websockets using classmediators

Comment: Thanks - I'll research ClassMediators.

Comment: I should have mentioned that the clients are all on external networks and won't have access to the ESB, only web services.